# on_member_join wont give role to the joined member

Tags: python, discord.py, nextcord

i am trying to do a "on member join" auto role + message event, its in a cog. When a Person joins the autorole doesnt work and no message is being send in the specific channel

ive tried it as a command, the member add roles and channel send work just as intended, but when tried in a event... it wont do anything. No role updates, no welcome messages, no errors.

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_member_join(self, member):
    role = nextcord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=946872903155191838)
    channel = self.bot.get_channel(int(946479063617384558))
    await member.add_roles(role, reason="test")
    await channel.send(f"Welcome {member.mention}!")
```

Comment: Do you have member intents enabled?

Comment: i do not think so..?

Comment: Oh my! Thank you so much! i didnt even know that exsisted haha